# Meteor get data from form that is defined by a schema

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to set up a form that is for user creation. The emails portion of the schema is set up as an array:

```
...
"emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    blackbox: true
},
"emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
},
...
```

I use auto form to create the form inside of a template:

```
    {{#autoForm id="addUser" type="method" meteormethod="createUserwRole" collection="Users" schema=schema resetOnSuccess="true" }}
    <fieldset>
        {{> afQuickField name="fName" id="fName"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="lName" id="lName"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="username" id="username"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="emails" id="emails"}}
        {{> afFormGroup name="roles" options=options firstoption="Select Role" type="select-multiple" id="roles"}}
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUser">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  {{/autoForm}}
```

Then on submission I want to grab the data:

```
Template.addUser.events({
  'submit #addUser': function(e, t) {
    console.log("hit");
    console.log(t);
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = t.find("#emails.0.address").value;
    var username = t.find("#username").value;
    console.log(email);

        Meteor.call("createUserwRole", ({"email":email, "username":username}));
    }
});
```

But attempting to find emails.0.address returns the error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.find("#emails.0.address").value')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many things done incorrectly. Please go through the simple-schema and autoform README file. It is a pretty powerful package and does make a lot of things easier.

1. Your Schema.
   Use `blackbox: true` only if the field type is an `Object`.
2. Your Autoform.
   You have specified both `collection="Users"` `schema=schema`, please specify only one.
3. Your form handling.
   Use `AutoForm.hooks` instead of custom event listeners.

   AutoForm.hooks({
       addUser: {
           onSubmit: function (doc) {
               console.log( doc.emais[0].address );
               console.log( doc.username );
               return true;
           }
       }
   });

Comment: Thank you for correcting my problems, I am trying to get the Autoform.hooks to work and am getting the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Autoform`  Any idea as to what the problem is there?

Comment: Hey it should be `AutoForm` - uppercase F.

Comment: I get the same error with different variations of it `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AutoForm`

Comment: Where are you pasting the code? Which file and within which function?

Comment: It is in the js file within the `if (meteor.isClient)` block

Comment: Can you add it within `Template.addUser.onRendered(function (){ //paste it here });` and try?

Comment: Same error, but came from debug.js this time `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AutoForm`

Comment: Do you have this code on some online repo or meteorpad?

Comment: http://meteorpad.com/pad/44XbvKu7qtmj9Pdq2/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard
The function on the server gets called. I have just logged it. But there are far too many other mistakes.